# Flask import error running setup script

Tags: python, flask

I Have a Flask webapp im working on. Im using ZODB with Flask-ZODB extension.
I have a small script to initialize some default objects on my database, such as users and the  "indexes" that ill be using to store some data the users will submit.

structure looks like:

```
myproject/
   |- myproject/
   |    |- __init__.py
   |    |- models.py
   |    |- views.py
   |    |- database/
   |    |- static/
   |    |- templates/
   |
   |- run.py
   |- setup.py
```

the setup script looks like this:

**[setup.py]**

```
from myproject.models import Usuario
from ZODB.DB import DB
from ZODB.FileStorage import FileStorage
from flask.ext.zodb import BTree
import transaction

# add admin users
superU = Usuario("somemail@gmail.com", "xxx")
admin  = Usuario("admin@gmail.com", "yyy")

#create indexes
storage = FileStorage('myproject/database/db.fs')
conn = DB(storage)
db = conn.open().root()

for idx in ['usuarios', 'proyectos', 'informes', 'actividades', 'objetivos', 'usuarios']:
    if not idx in db.keys():
        db[idx] = BTree()

db['usuarios'][superU.id] = superU
db['usuarios'][admin.id] = admin

for usuario in db['usuarios'].values():
    print "Usuario '", usuario.email, "' added..."

transaction.commit();
conn.close();
```

And the models file

The **init** file

**[_*init*_.py]**

```
from flask import Flask
from models import Usuario

# configuration
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

from basedatos import Coleccion, Catalogo
coleccion = Coleccion(app)
catalogo  =  Catalogo()

import myproject.views
```

**[models.py]**

```
from flask import current_app as app
from flask.ext.zodb import Object, List, Dict
from flask_login import UserMixin
from itsdangerous import URLSafeSerializer
from hashlib import sha256


class Usuario(UserMixin):
    """
        Usuarios de la aplicacion
    """
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.passwordHash = sha256(password).hexdigest()
        self.id = email

    def get_auth_token(self):
        return URLSafeSerializer(app.secret_key, salt='id salt').dumps(self.id+self.passwordHash)
```

So the thing is that when I want to run my setup, i get this import error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 3, in
>   
>       from myproject.models import Usuario   File "S:\Fuentes\workspace\Python\flaskapps\myproject-app\myproject__init__.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from flask import Flask ImportError: No module named flask

When i run the app everything works just fine, i only have this issue when running the script from the console. (im on Windows)

---

Im closing this one, it was a virtualenv issue. It happens that if you exceute only setup.py or c:\Python27\python.exe setup.py it doesnt look in the sitePackages folder of the active venv. Solution is to call it just > python.exe setup.py

Comment: The error seems to be happening in `myproject/__init__.py` - could you post that code as well please?

Comment: Wait - you're using a file `setup.py` in your project root, but it's not a setuptools script but some script to create and initialize your DB? You should definitely name that something else, like `create_db.py`. And then the question is, how do you actually *install* your project and its dependencies (Flask, ZODB, ...)?

Comment: i've just added the init file. I havent got to that point, regarding instalation. I guess i will create a requirement.txt to deploy it in the host, and follow your advise and change setup to create_db or something like that. Thanks!